# Yahoo Mail stopped syncing

Tags: sync, email, 7.8, yahoo

The Yahoo Mail on both my wife's and my phone stopped syncing 4 days ago. We both have Samsung sgh-i667 running Windows Phone 7.8. Outlook, Windows Live and Gmail all sync, just not Yahoo. Updates perfectly on laptop. Also can't access Yahoo Mail in settings, account text name is dimmed.