# Email stopped syncing Error message 80072FA8

Tags: sync, 7.x, yahoo

In February 2016, my yahoo verizon email stopped syncing and I receive an error message 80072FA8 on my Nokia Lumina 900 Windows phone, Vers 7.8. I still receive my email on my Dell (running MS Windows 10), a Samsung tablet and a Nook tablet, all with the same account settings. I worked with my service provider who tried many things including, but not limited to, a hard reset. All were unsuccessful. I worked with MS Windows phone tech support and still no solution to the problem. I find it illogical that no one recognizes a specific error message and does not know how to correct it. Account settings have not changed: Pop3 incoming.yahoo.verizon.net,  Smtp outgoing.yahoo.verizon.net. Both require authentication. Both require secure connections. Incoming port 995, outgoing port 465. Also says, not updated, We're having a problem downloading messages. Make sure you have a connection and your acct info is correct. However, I have the latest published firmware revision update: 2175.2307.8862.13100.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/12389/106

Comment: Are you able to browser the Internet generally from your phone, including logging in to Yahoo email via the web browser?

Comment: Yes I can. I decided to change from Yahoo Verizon to simply Verizon email. I lost a lot of email information, but my frustration was high. I was able to get my email on my computer, tablets again but when I went to the Windows phone, it had recognized Verizon but interestingly it automatically entered incoming and outgoing settings which were different from the most recently published settings i used on my computer and tablets. BUT I was now able to get email. This worked by luck. The settings the phone put in do not match the published Verizon settings. I'm changing to an iphone.

Comment: This is exactly the same issue I have had for some weeks - same ports mentioned etc etc - and using a windows phone - the only difference being my internet provider is virginmedia. Did you find a solution? Or did it result in you changing your phone? sorry to trouble you. I relate to that same degree of frustration. Thank you.